# Unexpected end of file

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to run a functions to get related posts by tag, i've been getting a `unexpected end of file` error and after some debugging i found out that it's this query causing the error. I've tried lots of solutions but can't seem to fix the issue !

This is the query that is placed in the beginning of my single.php file

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
echo 'Related Posts';
$first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
$args_related=array(
'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>10,
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$related_articles_query = new WP_Query($args_related);
```

This is how i'm using it in the template

```
      <div class="cards display--flex ">
                <?php if ($related_articles_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($related_articles_query->have_posts()) : $related_articles_query->the_post(); ?>

                <!-- =============================== -->
                <!-- Card Template -->
                <div class="card">
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( ))  : ?>

                    <div class="card__image display--flex">
                        <!--imagem -->
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end-magem -->
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <!-- none -->
                    <div class="card__image__none">
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <!-- end-none -->
                    <div class="card__container">
                        <p class="card__container__subtitle">
                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <h2 class="card__container__title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                 <!--   -->
                </div>
                <!--card  -->
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>
                <!-- =============================== -->
                <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php __('No Page Found'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- Card container-->
```

This is inside a single article and i'm creating a slider that has the related posts using `glider.js` , thats why i need the related articles

Comment: where did you close **if ($tags) {**  in code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent closing your `if` tag:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
    echo 'Related Posts';
    $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
    $args_related = array(
        'tag__in' => array($first_tag), 
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1
    );
    $related_articles_query = new WP_Query($args_related);
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks!